# How to aggregate Millions of records from text file and display in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I have millions of records in text file, i have to display data in d3 charts, need some aggregation mechanism that aggregates millions of records based on xaxis (day_of_Week)column and yaxis(Units) column and send the aggregated results to populate d3 charts, please advice me on this.

Comment: what do you have so far, what do your records look like

Comment: I'm down-voting this. Adds no relevant detail to the previous questions asked on exactly this topic. You need to explain your current database/aggregation approach so that we can help you improve it. D3 is essentially irrelevant to this question.

Comment: I should have noted that when I say "previous questions asked on exactly this topic", I mean the questions asked by this particular user. Not questions on SO in general :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use crossfilter.js [API](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference) or [DC.js](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/)
If you could share more info It would help to provide A detailed solution